# Extending Green's theorem from very special regions to more general regions

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

**Green's theorem**

Let $C$ be a positively oriented and consists of a finite union of disjoint,piecewise smooth simple closed curve in a plane, and let $D$ be the region bounded by $C$. If $P$ and $Q$ are functions of $(x, y)$ defined on an open region containing $D$ and have continuous partial derivatives there, then
$$\oint_C (Pdx+Qdy)=\iint_D (\frac{\partial Q }{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dxdy$$where the path of integration along $C$ is anticlockwise.

In almost all textbooks, authors only proved it when $D$ is [a simple region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Proof_when_D_is_a_simple_region) or the region $D$ can be cut up into finitely many simple regions without common interiors.My questions is how to
 generalize those special regions to more general regions as Green's theorem gives? I need a rigorous complete proof.Likewise Green's theorem,the divergence theorem and Stokes's theorem have the same situation requiring some rigorous proofs from very special regions to more general regions.

Comment: You may consult Federer, Geometric measure theory, or (for the beginners) F. Morgan, same title.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Professor, thanks for your references.But is there a rigorous proof only applying the knowledge/tools of real analysis, such as partition of unity?

Comment: Morgan's nook is aimed at advanced undergraduates.